# Contenttype for Documentset, site- and listcolumns

Tags: document-library, content-type, site-column, document-set

we created programmatically a contenttype for a documentset. In this contenttype are some other contenttypes for documents whic hare only allowed in the documentset-contenttyp. The documentset-contenttype uses some sitecolumns and for the other contenttypes there are sitecolumns too.

When adding the documentset-contenttype to a document library all site columns are activated for all other content types and the list of fields in the forms show all used sitecolumns.

Can we somehow just show the fields for the specific contenttype?

[Update]
Ok for example I've got a content type with parent document set named A. I've got two content types based on content type document which I'll name B and C.

In Content Type A I've got all site columns referenced I need. There are also all site columns I'll use in B and C.

B uses a subset of sitecolumns from A. C too. When uploading a new document and attaching the content type B to it all fields in A are shown in the Editform.

[Update 2]
This only appears on most of our dev-machine. One devsystem doens't have this effect.

Comment: Can you elaborate in which forms you see all used site columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with an Microsoft Application Development Consultant and he said that "feature" must have been implemented somewhere in CU july. Maybe it's fixed in a while.

Answer (score 1):

All columns of the content type will be added to library by default but it wont show up, when u create item using that content type. Can you be clear with your question?